# Interview advice - Google Developer Advocate position

Tags: interview, google

Can this position (Developer Advocate) be considered as a Software Engineering position in terms of interview questions they will likely ask me?

Anyone else been interviewed for this position? I am just trying to gauge what they'll ask me for Developer Advocate position. Thanks.

**EDIT:** This is just the first phone interview.

Comment: Related Programmers SE question: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/23810/upcoming-google-interview-looking-for-some-preparation-advice

Comment: Thanks but I still do not know if 'Developer Advocate' position has questions similar to Software Engineering position.

Comment: Can you give more info on the position? Are you an advocate for internal developers or someone who can go outside the company and be a voice for external developers? Either way, unless you're really hot looking, most programmers won't relate to you unless you can code.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I do understand I'd be required to code. I just wanted to know if the pattern of interview is similar with a Software Engineering interview.

Comment: @User007 - Welcome to Programmers.  Please read the site's FAQ and guidelines to asking questions.  Once you do, you'll want to come back here and edit this question to meet those guidelines.

Comment: This question appears to be the very definition of "Too Localised" - "This question would only be relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a brief Google search I would expect a developer advocate to be someone with a broad range of technical development experience who has deep experience in an area where Google is exposing an API. If none of this makes sense, you will likely be over your head. You should already be blogging about technology, an acknowledged expert in your field, and super confident about your coding ability.

Also, be prepared to kiss off your personal life, as they will suck your soul into the borg. Just kidding!

Comment: No not kidding. Look at the other guys (also from Microsoft), they blog almost from their bathrooms, from planes, hotels on the weekends and so on. Seemingly they've got no life at all.

Comment: @Developer Art - They have a life, it just doesn't extend beyond the walls of work. :)  Of course, every now and then one of these people posts a picture of themselves hanging onto a cliff or doing something outdoorsy and exciting.  The intent is to make it appear like they live an exciting life :)